# Unable to use SnmpTranslate with HP MIBs

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I'm trying to use SnmpTranslate to translate the SNMP traps sent by my ProLiant DL360p Gen8 server.  I used the MIB files from the Insight Management MIB update kit - http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/mibkit.html - as recommended here - http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/I-want-to-download-DL-380p-Gen8-Mib/td-p/5877083#.U8U63fmSwlo

However, when trying the following, I encountered a long list of errors.  Any tip will be much appreciated.

```
snmptranslate.exe -M mibs\mibs -mALL -Td .1.3.6.1.4.1.232.0.3046

No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
Did not find 'mgmt' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/rfc1213.mib)
Unlinked OID in RFC1213-MIB: mib-2 ::= { mgmt 1 }
Undefined identifier: mgmt near line 16 of mibs\mibs/rfc1213.mib
Unlinked OID in ZTSAMIB: enterprises ::= { private 1 }
Undefined identifier: private near line 27 of mibs\mibs/ztsa.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/ztmx.mib)
Unlinked OID in SNMP-TMUX-MIB: tandem ::= { enterprises 169 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 22 of mibs\mibs/ztmx.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/zsmp.mib)
Unlinked OID in SNMP-AGENT-PUBLIC-MIB: tandem ::= { enterprises 169 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 42 of mibs\mibs/zsmp.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/zhrm.mib)
Unlinked OID in SNMP-HMSA-MIB: tandem ::= { enterprises 169 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 22 of mibs\mibs/zhrm.mib
Unlinked OID in EthernetSubagentPvt-MIB: enterprises ::= { private 1 }
Undefined identifier: private near line 22 of mibs\mibs/zesa.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/xp1024trapmib.mib)
Unlinked OID in RAID450MIB: hitachi ::= { enterprises 116 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 17 of mibs\mibs/xp1024trapmib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/xl_hsv_200.mib)
Unlinked OID in CPQHSV200V6-MIB: compaq ::= { enterprises 232 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of mibs\mibs/xl_hsv_200.mib
Expected "(" (_): At line 383 in mibs\mibs/wbt3mib.mib
Should be ACCESS (port-modem): At line 383 in mibs\mibs/wbt3mib.mib
Bad parse of OBJECT-TYPE: At line 383 in mibs\mibs/wbt3mib.mib
Did not find 'vmDisplayName' in module VMWARE-VMINFO-MIB (mibs\mibs/VMWARE-TRAPS
-MIB.mib)
Unlinked OID in HOST-RESOURCES-MIB: mib-2 ::= { mgmt 1 }
Undefined identifier: mgmt near line 14 of mibs\mibs/rfc1514.mib
Group not found in module (hrSystemGroup): At line 118 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGENT
CAP-MIB.mib
Group not found in module (hrStorageGroup): At line 119 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGEN
TCAP-MIB.mib
Group not found in module (hrDeviceGroup): At line 120 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGENT
CAP-MIB.mib
Group not found in module (hrSWRunGroup): At line 121 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGENTC
AP-MIB.mib
Group not found in module (hrSWRunPerfGroup): At line 122 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AG
ENTCAP-MIB.mib
Group not found in module (hrSWInstalledGroup): At line 123 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-
AGENTCAP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrSystemNumUsers): At line 126 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-A
GENTCAP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrSWRunName): At line 130 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGENTC
AP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrDeviceErrors): At line 134 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGE
NTCAP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrSWOSIndex): At line 142 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AGENTC
AP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrFSLastFullBackupDate): At line 146 in mibs\mibs/VM
WARE-AGENTCAP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrFSLastPartialBackupDate): At line 150 in mibs\mibs
/VMWARE-AGENTCAP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrPrinterStatus): At line 154 in mibs\mibs/VMWARE-AG
ENTCAP-MIB.mib
Object not found in module (hrPrinterDetectedErrorState): At line 158 in mibs\mi
bs/VMWARE-AGENTCAP-MIB.mib
Did not find 'zeroDotZero' in module SNMPv2-SMI (mibs\mibs/vc-module-mib.mib)
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/vc-module-mib.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPVCMODULE-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 29 of mibs\mibs/vc-module-mib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/vc-qos-mib.mib)
Did not find 'virtualConnect' in module HPVCMODULE-MIB (mibs\mibs/vc-qos-mib.mib
)
Unlinked OID in HPVCQOS-MIB: vcQoSMIB ::= { virtualConnect 5 }
Undefined identifier: virtualConnect near line 27 of mibs\mibs/vc-qos-mib.mib
Did not find 'zeroDotZero' in module SNMPv2-SMI (mibs\mibs/vc-domain-mib.mib)
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/vc-domain-mib.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPVC-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 28 of mibs\mibs/vc-domain-mib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/brocade-reg-mib.mib)

Unlinked OID in Brocade-REG-MIB: bcsi ::= { enterprises 1588 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 41 of mibs\mibs/brocade-reg-mib.mib
Did not find 'bcsiModules' in module Brocade-REG-MIB (mibs\mibs/brocade-tc.mib)
Unlinked OID in Brocade-TC: bcsiModuleTC ::= { bcsiModules 2 }
Undefined identifier: bcsiModules near line 21 of mibs\mibs/brocade-tc.mib
Did not find 'fcSwitch' in module Brocade-REG-MIB (mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib)
Did not find 'bcsiModules' in module Brocade-REG-MIB (mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib)
Unlinked OID in SW-MIB: swMibModule ::= { bcsiModules 3 }
Undefined identifier: bcsiModules near line 28 of mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib
Unlinked OID in SW-MIB: sw20x0 ::= { fcSwitch 4 }
Undefined identifier: fcSwitch near line 81 of mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib
Unlinked OID in SW-MIB: sw21kN24k ::= { fcSwitch 3 }
Undefined identifier: fcSwitch near line 75 of mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib
Unlinked OID in SW-MIB: sw28k ::= { fcSwitch 2 }
Undefined identifier: fcSwitch near line 69 of mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib
Unlinked OID in SW-MIB: sw ::= { fcSwitch 1 }
Undefined identifier: fcSwitch near line 63 of mibs\mibs/v5_3sw.mib
Did not find 'fibrechannel' in module Brocade-REG-MIB (mibs\mibs/v5_1ha.mib)
Did not find 'swID' in module SW-MIB (mibs\mibs/v5_1ha.mib)
Did not find 'swSsn' in module SW-MIB (mibs\mibs/v5_1ha.mib)
Unlinked OID in HA-MIB: haMIB ::= { fibrechannel 2 }
Undefined identifier: fibrechannel near line 13 of mibs\mibs/v5_1ha.mib
Did not find 'fcSwitch' in module Brocade-REG-MIB (mibs\mibs/v5_0ficon.mib)
Unlinked OID in LINK-INCIDENT-MIB: linkIncidentMIB ::= { fcSwitch 50 }
Undefined identifier: fcSwitch near line 17 of mibs\mibs/v5_0ficon.mib
Did not find 'mgmt' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/svrclu.mib)
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/svrclu.mib)
Unlinked OID in SVRCLU-MIB: dec ::= { enterprises 36 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 50 of mibs\mibs/svrclu.mib
Did not find 'svrCluster' in module SVRCLU-MIB (mibs\mibs/truclu.mib)
Did not find 'svrCluMemberIndex' in module SVRCLU-MIB (mibs\mibs/truclu.mib)
Unlinked OID in TRUCLUSTER-SERVER-MIB: svrUNIXCluster ::= { svrCluster 3 }
Undefined identifier: svrCluster near line 38 of mibs\mibs/truclu.mib
Did not find 'mib-2' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/token.mib)
Unlinked OID in RFC1231-MIB: transmission ::= { mib-2 10 }
Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 19 of mibs\mibs/token.mib
Did not find 'mib-2' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/rfc1271-mib.mib)
Unlinked OID in RFC1271-MIB: rmon ::= { mib-2 16 }
Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 14 of mibs\mibs/rfc1271-mib.mib
Did not find 'rmon' in module RFC1271-MIB (mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.mib)
Did not find 'statistics' in module RFC1271-MIB (mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.m
ib)
Did not find 'history' in module RFC1271-MIB (mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.mib)

Unlinked OID in TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB: tokenRingPHistoryTable ::= { history 4 }
Undefined identifier: history near line 1123 of mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.mi
b
Unlinked OID in TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB: tokenRingMLHistoryTable ::= { history 3 }
Undefined identifier: history near line 731 of mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.mib

Unlinked OID in TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB: tokenRing ::= { rmon 10 }
Undefined identifier: rmon near line 34 of mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.mib
Unlinked OID in TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB: tokenRingPStatsTable ::= { statistics 3 }
Undefined identifier: statistics near line 428 of mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.
mib
Unlinked OID in TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB: tokenRingMLStatsTable ::= { statistics 2 }
Undefined identifier: statistics near line 42 of mibs\mibs/token-ring-rmon-mib.m
ib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/symtrap.mib)
Unlinked OID in SYMTRAP-MIB: symbios ::= { enterprises 1123 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 26 of mibs\mibs/symtrap.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/switch.mib)
Unlinked OID in SnetSwitch-MIB: tandem ::= { enterprises 169 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 85 of mibs\mibs/switch.mib
Did not find 'mgmt' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/svrntc.mib)
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/svrntc.mib)
Unlinked OID in SVRNTCLU-MIB: dec ::= { enterprises 36 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 49 of mibs\mibs/svrntc.mib
Did not find 'mgmt' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/svrmgt.mib)
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/svrmgt.mib)
Unlinked OID in SVRMGT-MIB: dec ::= { enterprises 36 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 25 of mibs\mibs/svrmgt.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/smsagent.mib)
Unlinked OID in SMSAGENT-MIB: unisys ::= { enterprises 223 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 11 of mibs\mibs/smsagent.mib
Did not find 'mib-2' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/rmon2-mib.mib)
Did not find 'ifIndex' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/rmon2-mib.mib)
Did not find 'tokenRing' in module TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB (mibs\mibs/rmon2-mib.mib)

Did not find 'tokenRingMLStatsEntry' in module TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB (mibs\mibs/rm
on2-mib.mib)
Did not find 'tokenRingPStatsEntry' in module TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB (mibs\mibs/rmo
n2-mib.mib)
Did not find 'ringStationControlEntry' in module TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB (mibs\mibs/
rmon2-mib.mib)
Did not find 'sourceRoutingStatsEntry' in module TOKEN-RING-RMON-MIB (mibs\mibs/
rmon2-mib.mib)
Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB: rmon ::= { mib-2 16 }
Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 47 of mibs\mibs/rmon2-mib.mib
Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB: sourceRoutingStats2Table ::= { tokenRing 8 }
Undefined identifier: tokenRing near line 4953 of mibs\mibs/rmon2-mib.mib
Unlinked OID in RMON2-MIB: ringStationControl2Table ::= { tokenRing 7 }
Undefined identifier: tokenRing near line 4902 of mibs\mibs/rmon2-mib.mib
Did not find 'mgmt' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/rfc1158.mib)
Unlinked OID in RFC1158-MIB: mib-2 ::= { mgmt 1 }
Undefined identifier: mgmt near line 15 of mibs\mibs/rfc1158.mib
Did not find 'mib-2' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/rfc1215.mib)
Did not find 'ifIndex' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/rfc1215.mib)
Did not find 'egpNeighAddr' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/rfc1215.mib)
Unlinked OID in RFC1215-MIB: snmp ::= { mib-2 11 }
Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 6 of mibs\mibs/rfc1215.mib
Did not find 'mib-2' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/bridge.mib)
Unlinked OID in BRIDGE-MIB: dot1dBridge ::= { mib-2 17 }
Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 126 of mibs\mibs/bridge.mib
Did not find 'dot1dTp' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dTpPort' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dBridge' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dBasePortEntry' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.m
ib)
Did not find 'dot1dBasePort' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib)
Unlinked OID in P-BRIDGE-MIB: dot1dTpPortOverflowTable ::= { dot1dTp 6 }
Undefined identifier: dot1dTp near line 674 of mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib
Unlinked OID in P-BRIDGE-MIB: dot1dTpHCPortTable ::= { dot1dTp 5 }
Undefined identifier: dot1dTp near line 595 of mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib
Unlinked OID in P-BRIDGE-MIB: pBridgeMIB ::= { dot1dBridge 6 }
Undefined identifier: dot1dBridge near line 19 of mibs\mibs/p-bridge-mib.mib
Did not find 'dot1dBridge' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/q-bridge.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dBasePortEntry' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/q-bridge.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dBasePort' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/q-bridge.mib)
Unlinked OID in Q-BRIDGE-MIB: qBridgeMIB ::= { dot1dBridge 7 }
Undefined identifier: dot1dBridge near line 32 of mibs\mibs/q-bridge.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/radlan-mib.mib)
Did not find 'RowPointer' in module SNMPv2-TC-v1 (mibs\mibs/radlan-mib.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dBasePort' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/radlan-mib.mib)
Did not find 'dot1dBasePortEntry' in module BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/radlan-mib.mib
)
Did not find 'dot1qFdbId' in module Q-BRIDGE-MIB (mibs\mibs/radlan-mib.mib)
Unlinked OID in RADLAN-MIB: rnd ::= { enterprises 89 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 166 of mibs\mibs/radlan-mib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/powernet.mib)
Unlinked OID in PowerNet-MIB: apc ::= { enterprises 318 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 23 of mibs\mibs/powernet.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/pfc.mib)
Did not find 'mgmt' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/pfc.mib)
Unlinked OID in PATROL-MIB: bmc ::= { enterprises 1031 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 20 of mibs\mibs/pfc.mib
Unlinked OID in PATROL-MIB: mib-2 ::= { mgmt 1 }
Undefined identifier: mgmt near line 17 of mibs\mibs/pfc.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/pcisnet.mib)
Unlinked OID in ServerNetPCI-MIB: tandem ::= { enterprises 169 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 112 of mibs\mibs/pcisnet.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/parselog.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSASEL-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 54 of mibs\mibs/parselog.mib
Did not find 'tcpConnLocalAddress' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-tc
p.mib)
Did not find 'tcpConnLocalPort' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-tcp.m
ib)
Did not find 'tcpConnRemAddress' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-tcp.
mib)
Did not find 'tcpConnRemPort' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-tcp.mib
)
Did not find 'ipAdEntAddr' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-ip.mib)
Did not find 'ipRouteDest' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-ip.mib)
Did not find 'ifIndex' in module RFC1213-MIB (mibs\mibs/old-cisco-interfaces.mib
)
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nwserver.mib)
Unlinked OID in NetWare-Server-MIB: novell ::= { enterprises 23 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 23 of mibs\mibs/nwserver.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nwalarm.mib)
Unlinked OID in NetWare-Server-Alarm-MIB: novell ::= { enterprises 23 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 22 of mibs\mibs/nwalarm.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsnicmib.mib)
Unlinked OID in NSNICMIB-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 236 of mibs\mibs/nsnicmib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsavolcp.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSASTORAGECAP-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 73 of mibs\mibs/nsavolcp.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsatrmgr.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSATRAPMNGR-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 75 of mibs\mibs/nsatrmgr.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsatrcfg.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSATRAPCFG-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 44 of mibs\mibs/nsatrcfg.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsascsi.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSASCSI-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 84 of mibs\mibs/nsascsi.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsarps.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSARPS-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 20 of mibs\mibs/nsarps.mib
Expected "(" (_): At line 356 in mibs\mibs/nsapci.mib
Should be ACCESS (Computer): At line 356 in mibs\mibs/nsapci.mib
Bad parse of OBJECT-TYPE: At line 356 in mibs\mibs/nsapci.mib
Expected "(" (_): At line 282 in mibs\mibs/nsainfo.mib
Should be ACCESS (Vectra): At line 282 in mibs\mibs/nsainfo.mib
Bad parse of OBJECT-TYPE: At line 282 in mibs\mibs/nsainfo.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsaevent.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSAEVENT-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 119 of mibs\mibs/nsaevent.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsadimm.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSADIMM-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 66 of mibs\mibs/nsadimm.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/nsaasr.mib)
Unlinked OID in HPNSAASR-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 42 of mibs\mibs/nsaasr.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/ndstrap.mib)
Unlinked OID in Novell-Directory-Services-Trap-MIB: novell ::= { enterprises 23
}
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 18 of mibs\mibs/ndstrap.mib
Did not find 'experimental' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/fa-mib40.mib)
Unlinked OID in FCMGMT-MIB: fcmgmt ::= { experimental 94 }
Undefined identifier: experimental near line 69 of mibs\mibs/fa-mib40.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/msa2000traps.mib)
Did not find 'connUnitEventId' in module FCMGMT-MIB (mibs\mibs/msa2000traps.mib)

Did not find 'connUnitEventType' in module FCMGMT-MIB (mibs\mibs/msa2000traps.mi
b)
Did not find 'connUnitEventDescr' in module FCMGMT-MIB (mibs\mibs/msa2000traps.m
ib)
Unlinked OID in MSA2000TRAPS-MIB: hp ::= { enterprises 11 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 45 of mibs\mibs/msa2000traps.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/mlxraid.mib)
Unlinked OID in MYLEXRAID-MIB: mylex ::= { enterprises 1608 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 22 of mibs\mibs/mlxraid.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/lsf001.mib)
Unlinked OID in LSF-SNMP-MIB: platform ::= { enterprises 2766 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 12 of mibs\mibs/lsf001.mib
Undefined OBJECT-GROUP (ifGeneralInformationGroup): At line 1960 in mibs\mibs/ll
dp-v2-mib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/le_hsv_300.mib)
Unlinked OID in CPQHSV300V11-MIB: compaq ::= { enterprises 232 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of mibs\mibs/le_hsv_300.mib
Expected "(" (_): At line 2139 in mibs\mibs/ibrixMib.mib
Should be ACCESS (fwUpdateBegin): At line 2139 in mibs\mibs/ibrixMib.mib
Bad parse of OBJECT-TYPE: At line 2139 in mibs\mibs/ibrixMib.mib
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/ums.mib)
Unlinked OID in UMS-MIB: ibm ::= { enterprises 2 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 10 of mibs\mibs/ums.mib
Did not find 'director' in module UMS-MIB (mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib)
Did not find 'ibmpsg' in module UMS-MIB (mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib)
Did not find 'ibmpsgEvent' in module UMS-MIB (mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib)
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 2028 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1960 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1893 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1827 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1761 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1686 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1611 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1535 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1469 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1402 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1335 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1269 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1204 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1139 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1073 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 1007 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 939 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 873 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 807 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 741 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 676 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 611 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 544 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 479 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 408 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 343 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 276 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 212 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 145 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: ibmpsg# ::= { ibmpsg 0 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsg near line 78 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGGenericVoltageEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEven
t 32 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1963 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGGenericFanEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 31
 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1896 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGDASDBackplaneEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent
 30 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1830 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGSPPowerSupplyEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent
 29 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1764 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGNetworkAdapterOnlineEventBindings ::= { ibmp
sgEvent 28 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1689 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGNetworkAdapterOfflineEventBindings ::= { ibm
psgEvent 27 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1614 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGNetworkAdapterFailedEventBindings ::= { ibmp
sgEvent 26 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1538 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGRemoteLoginEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 2
5 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1472 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGErrorLogEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 24 }

Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1405 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGPowerSupplyEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 2
3 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1338 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGPFAEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 22 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1272 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGMemoryPFEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 19 }

Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1207 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGProcessorPFEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent 1
8 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1142 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGRedundantNICSwitchbackEventBindings ::= { ib
mpsgEvent 17 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1076 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGRedundantNICSwitchoverEventBindings ::= { ib
mpsgEvent 16 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 1010 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGRedundantNICEventBindings ::= { ibmpsgEvent
15 }
Undefined identifier: ibmpsgEvent near line 942 of mibs\mibs/ibmumsevent.mib
Unlinked OID in UMSEVENT-MIB: iBMPSGWarrantyExpirationEventBindings ::= { ibmpsg

)
Unlinked OID in CPQHSV360V11-MIB: compaq ::= { enterprises 232 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of mibs\mibs/ashcroft_hsv_360.mib
```

< Truncated as too long >

```
Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/ashcroft_hsv_340.mib
)
Unlinked OID in CPQHSV340V11-MIB: compaq ::= { enterprises 232 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 39 of mibs\mibs/ashcroft_hsv_340.mib

Did not find 'enterprises' in module RFC1155-SMI (mibs\mibs/adaptec.mib)
Unlinked OID in CYCLONE-MIB: adaptec ::= { enterprises 795 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 22 of mibs\mibs/adaptec.mib
CPQIDA-MIB::cpqDa7PhyDrvStatusChange
cpqDa7PhyDrvStatusChange OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM       CPQIDA-MIB
  OBJECTS       { sysName, cpqHoTrapFlags, cpqDaCntlrHwLocation, cpqDaPhyDrvCntl
rIndex, cpqDaPhyDrvIndex, cpqDaPhyDrvLocationString, cpqDaPhyDrvType, cpqDaPhyDr
vModel, cpqDaPhyDrvFWRev, cpqDaPhyDrvSerialNum, cpqDaPhyDrvFailureCode, cpqDaPhy
DrvStatus, cpqDaPhyDrvBusNumber }
  DESCRIPTION   "Physical Drive Status Change.

This trap signifies that the agent has detected a change in the status of a drive array physical drive.  The variable cpaDaPhyDrvStatus indicates the current physical drive status.

User Action: If cpaDaPhyDrvStatus is 'failed(3)','predictiveFailure(4)', 'ssdWearOut(8)', or 'notAuthenticated(9)',replace the drive." ::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) compaq(232) compaq#(0) 3046 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the default MIBs and it cannot fully build the tree.